# android async http client cookie does not work

Tags: android, cookies

I tried to get cookie data after requestted url.
It works with http sync client.
But it does not work with this library.

Please see these code with sync client

```
       **HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
        httpPost.setURI(url); 
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> post = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String strID = et_id.getText().toString().trim();
        String strPW = et_pw.getText().toString().trim();
        String strTStamp = Util.getTimeStamp();
        String headerData = strTStamp + Util.rpad(strID, ID_LENGTH, " ") + strPW;
        String tmpData = (Util.bin2hex(Util.hmacSha512(headerData, KEY))).toLowerCase();
        Log.e(TAG, "ID:" + strID + " / PW:" + strPW +" / TS:"+strTStamp);
        Log.e(TAG, "ORG_DATA:"+headerData);
        Log.e(TAG, "SHA_DATA:"+tmpData);
        httpPost.setHeader(NAME_HD, tmpData);                   // Set Header
        post.add(new BasicNameValuePair(NAME_ID, strID));       // Set ID
        post.add(new BasicNameValuePair(NAME_PW, strPW));       // Set PW
        post.add(new BasicNameValuePair(NAME_TS, strTStamp));   // Set Time
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(post));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
        Log.e(TAG, "ResponseString :"+responseString);
        List<Cookie> cookies = ((DefaultHttpClient)client).getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if(!cookies.isEmpty()){
            for(int i = 0; i<cookies.size(); i++){
                String strCookie = cookies.get(i).getName()+"="+cookies.get(i).getValue();
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie :" + cookies.get(i).toString());
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie :" + strCookie);
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie Domain :" + cookies.get(i).getDomain());
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie Path :" + cookies.get(i).getPath());
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie ExpiryDate :" + cookies.get(i).getExpiryDate());
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie Name :" + cookies.get(i).getName());
                Log.e(TAG, "Cookie Value :" + cookies.get(i).getValue());
                cm.setCookie(MAIN_URL, strCookie);
                csm.getInstance().sync();
                String msg = " Cookie Name : " + cookies.get(i).getName();
                msg += "\n\n Cookie Value : " + cookies.get(i).getValue();
                msg += "\n\n Cookie Domain : " + cookies.get(i).getDomain();
                msg += "\n\n Cookie Path : " + cookies.get(i).getPath();
                msg += "\n\n Cookie ExpiryDate : " + cookies.get(i).getExpiryDate();
                tv_msg.setText(msg);
            }
        }**
```

result: cookie list.count = 1

But it does not work with asyn library

result: cookie list.count = 0

Comment: Please add some details too

Comment: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/1033 please see it.

Comment: resolve by using 1.4.9